# Calcular o total da Receita de Vendas

Tags: java, primefaces, jpa-2.0, cdi

possuo uma página de consulta que mostra o total da receita para cada produto e quero calcular o total do somatório das receitas mas está dando errado a conta. O correto fazendo o somatório na mão deu 264.660,00 e fazendo em java deu 18.830,00

https://snag.gy/SGFPKw.jpg

Para calcular este somatório utilizei o seguinte :

```
public Long buscaTotalParaDiretor(Long codigo) {
    String codigoProduto = "";
    String codigoProdutoAnterior ="";
    List<Produto> produtos = manager
            .createQuery("select p from Produto p where p.empresa.codigo =:codigo order by trim(p.codigoProduto)",
                    Produto.class)
            .setParameter("codigo", codigo).getResultList();
    Long totalReceita = 0L;
    Long receita = 0L;
    Long soma = 0L;

    int i = 0;
    for (Produto p : produtos) {
        if (i == 0) {
            codigoProdutoAnterior = p.getCodigoProduto().trim();
        }
        if (codigoProdutoAnterior.equals(p.getCodigoProduto().trim())) {
            soma += p.getQuantidadeRecente();
             System.out.println("Codigo " + codigoProduto +" Soma + " + soma + "Valor: " + p.getValor());
            receita = soma * p.getValor().longValue();
            System.out.println("Receita + " + receita);
            totalReceita += receita;
            System.out.println("Total + " + totalReceita);
        }
        codigoProduto = p.getCodigoProduto().trim();
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println("Total : " + totalReceita);
    return totalReceita;
}
```

O bean :

```
public class PrevisaoDiretorBean implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private Produtos previsoes;

@Inject
@UsuarioLogado
private Usuario usuario;

private List<Filtro> listaDePrevisoes = new ArrayList<>();

public List<Filtro> getPrevisoes() {
    return listaDePrevisoes;
}

public void inicializar() {
    if (FacesUtil.isNotPostback()) {

        listaDePrevisoes = previsoes.listarProdutosDoDiretor(usuario.getEmpresa().getCodigo());

    }
}

public List<Filtro> getListaDePrevisoes() {
    return listaDePrevisoes;
}

public void setListaDePrevisoes(List<Filtro> listaDePrevisoes) {
    this.listaDePrevisoes = listaDePrevisoes;
}

public Long getTotal() {

    Long totalReceita = previsoes.buscaTotalParaDiretor(usuario.getEmpresa().getCodigo());
    return totalReceita;
}
```

}

e o xhtml:

```
<p:column headerText=" Receita Total"
                    style="text-align: center; width: 140px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{produto.receita}">
                        <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2"
                            maxFractionDigits="2" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>


                <p:columnGroup type="footer">
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column colspan="6" footerText="Receita Total :"
                            style="text-align: right;background:navy;color: Snow;" />
                        <p:column style="text-align: right;background:navy;color: Snow;">
                            <f:facet name="footer">
                                <h:outputText value="#{previsaoDiretorBean.total}" >
                                <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2"
                                    maxFractionDigits="2" />
                                </h:outputText>

                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                </p:columnGroup>


            </p:dataTable>


        </h:form>
```

A saída no console é a seguinte :

```
Codigo  Soma + 102Valor: 2.30
Receita + 204
Total + 204
Codigo 0124940 Soma + 151Valor: 2.30
Receita + 302
Total + 506
Total : 506
Como se pode ver não é o resultado que quero.
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara, aparentemente sua somatória está correta, talvez o problema não seja na primeira iteração do loop?

Pois na primeira iteração neste if

```
 if (codigoProduto.equals(p.getCodigoProduto().trim()))
```

o seu codigoProduto é igual a "", então creio que ai ele deixa de somar o primeiro valor da sua receita.

Talvez se você inicializar sua variável com o valor da primeira posição da lista, sua soma passe a dar o resultado correto.

Comment: o problema é na lógica mesmo. . enquanto os codigos de produto forem iguais eu faoço a soma e calculo a receita que é a soma * valor . A receita total é a soma das receitas. è isto que eu estou com dificuldade de implementar. Dei uma alterada no codigo .

Comment: Você já tentou dar um print nos valores da lista?
Pode ser que tenha alguma falha no select e nesse ponto ele não está trazendo todos os dados que você precisa.

Comment: Você considerou fazer esse cálculo no SQL? Não entendi corretamente sua necessidade, mas é uma opção. Caso contrário, pelo que entendi, você pode armazenar cada produto em um array depois realizar a soma no fim.